# Windows Ribbon Framework: Does not highlight on hover

Tags: delphi, frameworks, ribbon

I am building an application which has Windows Ribbon at the top a panel with embedded 3rd party application at the bottom. As soon as embedded app loads, the main application form becomes inactive (title text becomes gray). This is expected behavior, however my problem is - unlike all other controls on the inactive main form, Ribbon tabs and the components they contain become unresponsive to mouse movements, i.e. do not highlight buttons on mouse over, do not show hints, etc. The only part of the Ribbon that works correctly on inactive form is Quick Access Toolbar. As the result, after interacting with embedded app user needs to click twice on the ribbon control to trigger an action.

The sample apps provided with Ribbon Framework do the same when they become inactive, so the issue is definitely not with my code.

I wonder if anyone else had similar experience and can suggest a workaround or a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: We can only guess what is going on here. Which ribbon framework? What does embedded app mean? If you have multiple processes then what you are attempting is basically untenable. You cannot expect it work work well.

Comment: We are still guessing. You need to show a [MCVE]

Comment: The question is about Delphi-Ribbon-Framework downloaded from https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework Compiler Delphi 10.1, OS Windows 10. For simplicity let's leave aside my application and talk about framework Sample project called "Text Pad". When Textpad window becomes inactive the buttons on its Quick Access Toolbar (QAT) are still highlighted on mouse over, while Ribbon tabs and all other controls on the ribbon are not. My question is - how to make all ribbon controls to behave the same - like QAT buttons when the application is not active. Thanks.

Comment: We can help when we have the [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that Microsoft Outlook and Excel behave exactly the same. Delphi-Ribbon-Framework uses native Windows API for creating ribbon, so this is not an issue with Delphi Ribbon Framework, or my code, but the way Microsoft implemented it.

Thanks.